# Calculating relation (employee's salary)/(deparment's salary contribution) for each employee

Tags: mysql

I'm beginning with SQL and I'm stuck with the following exercise:

> Calculate for each employee *the percent* that his wage (salary +
>   commission) represents from the total contribution salary of the department
>   he works in.

My scheme looks like this:

[image]

My attempt was this:

```
SELECT employee.last_name, temp1.department_id AS department, wage/deptwage*100 AS "%wage/deptwage"
FROM employee, 
(SELECT department_id, SUM(salary+COALESCE(commission, 0)) AS deptwage
FROM employee
GROUP BY department_id ) temp1,
(SELECT last_name, (salary+COALESCE(commission, 0)) AS wage
FROM employee ) temp2
WHERE temp1.department_id=employee.department_id
```

After executing the query I get basically this, with 1024 rows:

[image]

1024 came from 32*32: It's executing wage/deptwage*100 for each employee 32 times (which is the total number of employees).

I've tried without success to write a new script, so I'd really appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Please edit the headline of your question since it is very unclear what you mean.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a join:

```
SELECT      employee.last_name, 
            dep.department_id AS department, 
            (salary+COALESCE(commission, 0))*100/deptwage AS "%wage/deptwage"
FROM        employee
inner join (SELECT   department_id, 
                     SUM(salary+COALESCE(commission, 0)) AS deptwage
            FROM     employee
            GROUP BY department_id
           ) dep
        on  dep.department_id = employee.department_id
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't have idea about the `inner join` keyword, honestly. I'm reading about it right now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the 3rd table and JOIN the first 2:

```
SELECT 
    e.last_name, 
    d.department_id AS department, 
    -- wage/deptwage*100 AS "%wage/deptwage", -- remove this
    (e.salary + COALESCE(e.commission, 0)) / (d.deptwage * 100) as "% wage/deptwage"
FROM 
    employee e
JOIN
    (SELECT Employee_ID, department_id, SUM(salary + COALESCE(commission, 0)) AS deptwage
    FROM employee
    GROUP BY department_id) d
ON 
    e.Employee_ID = d.Employee_ID
WHERE 
    d.department_id = e.department_id
```